# NoReverseMatch - Simple Django forums application

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views, django-urls

I am attempting to create a simple forum application and am getting this error. I am inclined to think this may have something to do with my URLConf or possibly the way I am using the URL template tag to generate the URL for each thread.

**/forums/urls.py**

```
# ex: /forums/general_forum
url(r'^(?P<forum_slug>[-\w\d]+)/$', views.forum, name='forum'),

# ex: /forums/general_forum-1/my_first_thread
url(r'^(?P<forum_slug>[-\w\d]+)/(?P<thread_slug>[-\w\d]+)/$', views.thread, name='thread'),
```

**/forums/views.py**

The *index* view works fine, the *forum* view does not.

```
def index(request):
    context = RequestContext(request)
    forum_list = Forum.objects.order_by("sequence")

    for forum in forum_list:
        forum.url = slugify(forum.title) + "-" + str(forum.id)

    context_dict = {'forum_list': forum_list}
    return render_to_response('forums/index.html', context_dict, context)

@login_required
def forum(request, forum_slug):
    context = RequestContext(request)

    try:
        forum = Forum.objects.get(slug=forum_slug)

        threads = Thread.objects.filter(forum=forum)

        context_dict = {'forum': forum,
                        'threads': threads}

    except Forum.DoesNotExist:
        pass

    return render_to_response('forums/forum.html', context_dict, context)
```

This is how I am linking to the *forum* view inside index.html.

```
<a href={% url 'forum' forum.slug %}>{{ forum.title }}</a>
```

And in forum.html, this is how the links are formulated to view the posts inside the thread. This :

```
<a href={% url 'forum' forum.slug %}/{% url 'thread' thread.slug %}>{{ thread.title }}</a>
```

The error. One of the threads is titled 'django'

```
NoReverseMatch at /forums/web-development/

Reverse for 'thread' with arguments '(u'django',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 2 pattern(s) tried: ['forums/(?P<forum_slug>[-\\w\\d]+)/(?P<thread_slug>[-\\w\\d]+)/$', '$(?P<forum_slug>[-\\w\\d]+)/(?P<thread_slug>[-\\w\\d]+)/$']
```

In the error, the url template tag for 'thread' is highlighted in red and states there was an error during template rendering. This error seems unclear to me and I am not sure if this is an issue with the way I am using the template tags or something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not passing the Forum slug in your thread URL, which your URL configuration requires:

```
<a href={% url 'forum' forum.slug %}/{% url 'thread' thread.slug %}>{{ thread.title }}</a>
```

You should not be using both urls, either. Instead, what you want is:

```
<a href="{% url 'thread' forum.slug thread.slug %}">{{ thread.title }}</a>
```

Comment: Well, that was simple enough (and I thought I had tried that already). Now I feel dumb! Thanks so much :)